# browser notification onclick event doesn't get fired in chrome

Tags: javascript, notifications

I am creating browser notifications, and it works great in firefox and edge. But for some reason it is not working in chrome. I can see the notification but when i click on the notification it doesn't get fired.  This is my code:

```
function notifyMe(text) {
    if (Notification.permission !== "granted")
        Notification.requestPermission();
    else {
        var notification = new Notification('Notification title', {               
            body: text,
            requireInteraction: true     
        });
        notification.onclick = function (event) {
            alert("clicked");
            event.preventDefault(); 
            console.log('Notification clicked.');
        } 

    }      
}
```

So my question is, why the notificaion.onclick won't get triggered in chrome?

Answer (score -3, accepted):

You are probably clicking the close button, it does not trigger the click event, try clicking on anything other than close button, try to use `onclose` event

```
function notifyMe(text) {
    if (Notification.permission !== "granted")
        Notification.requestPermission();
    else {
        var notification = new Notification('Notification title', {               
            body: text,
            requireInteraction: true     
        });
        notification.onclick = function (event) {
            alert("onClick!");
            event.preventDefault(); 
            console.log('Notification clicked.');
        } 
        notification.onclose = function (event) {
            alert("onClose!");
            event.preventDefault(); 
            console.log('Notification clicked.');
        } 
    }      
}
```

Or Try to use `EventListener`:

```
function notifyMe(text) {
    if (Notification.permission !== "granted")
        Notification.requestPermission();
    else {
        var notification = new Notification('Notification title', {               
            body: text,
            requireInteraction: true     
        });
        notification.addEventListener("click", function (event) {
            alert("onClick!");
            event.preventDefault(); 
            console.log('Notification clicked.');
        } )
        notification.addEventListener("close", function (event) {
            alert("onClose!");
            event.preventDefault(); 
            console.log('Notification clicked.');
        } )

    }      
}
```

Comment: Close button works. If I click on close it closes the notification. But if I click anywhere else it opens a new window. And it does that only in chrome. In firefox and edge it displays an alert and it logs a message in console. When I debug and i put a break point inside notification.onclick, it does not go inside the function(in chrome, in others it works as expected). Thanks for your response.

Comment: very strange because I tested here and it worked everything except the close button, including to add the close button event, I had to add the event "onclose", I will update the answer

Comment: Are you testing it in google chrome? In edge and firefox it works.Chrome is the issue. I used your code and it is the same.

Comment: @brusli yes i have tested on Chrome, try to clean your js, or just execute on console by pressing f12

Comment: Thanks, it is working now. Still not sure what was the problem but now it works.

Comment: I have this same issue and I think it might be to do with the way Windows 10 / Chrome handles notifications. After a short period of time the 'click' eventHandler is removed becuase the 'close' is triggered even though it still appears in the notification list. I had expected the event.preventDefault() in the close to block this from happening, but it doesn't work. @brusli please can you share your working code.

Comment: @Demian Bibiano were you able to replicate the issue before providing the above solution?

Comment: I think it's to do with how long you wait before you click. Because after a short time the 'close' event is triggered which removes the 'click' event.